# Question regarding relation between determinant and trace

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prop 1.** Let $A$ and $P$ be the $n\times n$ matrices and $u_1, u_2, \cdots ,u_n$ be the columns of the matrix $P$.Then
$$\sum _{k = 1}^{n}\det[u_1, u_2,\cdots, Au_k, \cdots, u_n] = \operatorname{tr}(A)\det(P)$$ holds.

I have to prove Prop 1 to solve below problem:

Let $A(t)$ be the continuous family of $n\times n$ matrices and let $P(t)$ be the solution to the initial value problem $P' = A(t)P,P(0) = P_0$ show that
$$\det P(t) = (\det P_0)\exp (\int_{0}^{t} \operatorname{tr}(A(s)) \operatorname{ds})$$

which is in "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos"

However, I can't show Prop 1 is true. I tried to prove that by applying Laplace expension inductively but I couldn't calculate all sums. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum _k \det(x_1, x_2,\ldots, Ax_k, \ldots, x_n)$. $\phi$ is multilinear, alternating and $\phi(I) = \operatorname{tr} A$.

Hence $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (\operatorname{tr} A) \det X$.

Comment: $x_i$ don’t appear?

Comment: @TedShifrin My guardian angel...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. You gave me some motivation to study more linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the $u_i=e_i$ are just the standard basis vectors. Then $\det(e_1,...,Ae_k,...,e_n)$ is $A_{kk}$ and $\det(P)$ is $1$, so it works in this case. More generally, $u_k=Pe_k$ and so

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\det(u_1,...,Au_k,...,u_n)&=\sum_{k=1}^n\det(Pe_1,...,APe_k,...,Pe_n)\\
&=\det(P)\sum_{k=1}^n\det(e_1,...,P^{-1}APe_k,...,e_n)\\
&=\det(P)\operatorname{tr}(P^{-1}AP)\\
&=\det(P)\operatorname{tr}(A)
\end{align*}
This proves the claim if $P$ is invertible. I am confident the claim is true in general, but I do not have a proof in that case right now.

Comment: You can use the density of the invertible matrices.